# Is there a pythonic way to "hot swap" a list?

Tags: python, loops, hotswap

Generally modifying the list you're looping through is considered bad form, but I haven't found a pythonic way around my issue. The crux of the problem is that I have to start the loop and perform some actions before I will know how long my list will be. I can safely assume there is a least 1 item in this list, but that's all I know until I take the first steps.

**for some additional context:** I'm working with pyautogui. My script clicks a button and is then presented with multiple options, the number of options determines how many times I will need to click the button again

An example of the closest i've come:

```
x=[1] #initial 

y=[2,3,4,5] #stand in for unknown number of loops to make

for i in x:
     if i==1: #check some criteria to determine number of loops
         x.extend(y) #correct number of loops
     print(i) #do some stuff
```

Does anyone have any ideas on pythonic ways to "hotswap" lists like this?

Comment: Do you mean something like: There could be many different lists: `y1, y2, y3 ... ` which are selected at run-time?

Comment: If you're just using the list like a queue, then there's actually nothing technically wrong with this code. There are a few traps when modifying a list while iterating it, but you didn't fall into one. That being said, a more obviously queue-like structure (such as `collections.deque`) may be a more appropriate container choice than a list here.

Comment: It seems from the comment "correct number of loops" that you really do want to modify the list being iterated. In your case, the for loop will run through 1,2,3,4,5. Is that what you want?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes. In my actual case, i don't know `y` ahead of the loop starting but that is the idea

Comment: @wim thanks i'll look into collections

Comment: @quamrana no i mean the length of `y` is unknown before i start the first loop

Comment: A potential trap here is using an element of `x` to determine whether more elements should be added. Thus, in your example, if `y` always contained a `1`, the loop would never terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a list iterator is asked for the next value (perhaps with `next()`, a `for` or other mechanism), it checks whether it has reached the end and should raise `StopIteration`. The iteration is based on the index of the list and no matter how much the list has been shuffled around, it grabs the next indexed value. That means that even if you are iterating the very last value in the list, and you add more, the iteration will continue because you have not reached an index beyond the range of the list.

In your case, that's what you want. The `for` will be iterated once, but before returning to the next iteration, more values are added and those values will be iterated. And that's what your print statement shows

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

You don't need to know in advance how many values you will add. Whatever is in the next index position in the list continues the list.

S'all Good, Man.